# Hibernate @GeneratedValue null error for primary key

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, tomcat7

I am using Hibernate to save an object in the database. I am generating my primary key with @GeneratedValue annotation.

Here is my code Vendor class

```
  package com.samples.vendor;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Vendor")
public class Vendor implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="vendor_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int vendor_ID;
    private String vname;
    private long phone_no;
    private String emailID;
    @Transient
    private int updated;
    
    
    public int getVendor_ID() {
        return vendor_ID;
    }
    public void setVendor_ID(int vendor_ID) {
        this.vendor_ID = vendor_ID;
    }
    public String getVname() {
        return vname;
    }
    public void setVname(String vname) {
        this.vname = vname;
    }
    public long getPhone_no() {
        return phone_no;
    }
    public void setPhone_no(long phone_no) {
        this.phone_no = phone_no;
    }
    public String getEmailID() {
        return emailID;
    }
    public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
        this.emailID = emailID;
    }
    public int getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }
    public void setUpdated(int updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }
        
    }
```

I am using MS SQL Server 2012 where I have a vendor table with following columns

```
vendor_ID   int         Unchecked -------> Primary key
vname       varchar(50) Checked
phone_no    bigint      Checked
emailID     varchar(50) Checked
updated     bit         Checked
```

Unchecked means its NOTNULL = true, it doesnt allow null values.

Here is the code where I am trying to save the data into database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addVendor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addVendor(@ModelAttribute("vendor") Vendor vendor, BindingResult result)
{
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        ModelAndView modelErr = new ModelAndView("AddVendor");
        return modelErr;
    }
    Session session = null;
    try
    {
    
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(vendor);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        
        ModelAndView modelview = new ModelAndView("Insert");
        return modelview;
    
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
    return null;
```

When I run this, I get following error

```
 Hibernate: insert into Vendor (emailID, phone_no, vname) values (?, ?, ?)
Sep 12, 2015 7:45:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 515, SQLState: 23000
Sep 12, 2015 7:45:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'vendor_ID', table 'VendorCalls.dbo.Vendor'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2730)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3300)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at com.samples.vendor.InsertDB.addVendor(InsertDB.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'vendor_ID', table 'VendorCalls.dbo.Vendor'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the strategy javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY for @GeneratedValue your table must have an identity generator. This can be done including an AUTO_INCREMENT to your primary key.

Example:
CREATE TABLE Vendor
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

Comment: Doesn't hibernate generate an identity value by itself when we use @GeneratedValue annotation?
What I have understood is that I can change the column in my database to IDENTITY and can do away with AUTO_INCREMENT right?

Comment: Not necessarily, just tried an entity with (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) and it's table without AUTO_INCREMENT. Hibernate returned me an error saying the entity did not have an error default value for it's ID. After including AUTO_INCREMENT everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Your `vendor_ID` has no default value but it has `NOT NULL` constraint. When you're doing `INSERT`, you have to set `vendor_ID`, or if you don't want to set it manually then you should set `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute to generate a unique identity for new rows. Remember, if you don't set any value for your id field, it is supposed to be null or default value (or it will do an auto increment if you set that attribute).

The `@GeneratedValue` annotation just tells Hibernate that the database is generating this value itself. So the `AUTO_INCREMENT` should be defined in the database as well.

Comment: It worked. Only thing I had to do was add identity to the column. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the Hibernate ORM has been updated that much but currently you have to omit the decorator `@Column()` if you use `@GeneratedValue`.

So your code will be

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int vendor_ID;
```

instead of

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="vendor_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int vendor_ID;
```

Hope it helps.