# How to provide Initial value OR Increment ID with JPA GenerationType.AUTO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, post, spring-data-jpa

I am using following code to define `MyEntity`,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "MY_TABLE_ID")
private Integer myTableId;

@Column(name = "MY_TABLE_NM")
private String myTableName;

//Getters Setters
}
```

For the first `POST` after my application starts, I create `MyEntity` everything works fine, `MY_TABLE_ID` starts with 1 and works as expected.

My issue is, If somebody inserts data manually before I do my `POST` then I get *duplicate key exception* as `myTableId` is entered as 1 which is already present.

My main problem is I can't create `database sequence` for using `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` now to resolve this as database can't be altered now.
I have tried various combinations of `GenerationType`, `TableGenerator` but I am unable to successfully tackle it.

Setting `initialValue` to some larger number to avoid duplicate values can temporarily resolve my problem but I am unable to do it too.

If someone can help me with `initialValue` with `AUTO` or give me some other better solution without database changes will be great :)

Comment: How is the table set up? Is `MY_TABLE_ID` an identity column?

Comment: Yes, `MY_TABLE_ID` is an identity column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried various options in answers provided here and for similar questions on stackoverflow and other forums,

I had few limitations,

1. I couldn't create database sequence as my database changes were freezed.
2. I didn't want to introduce new `Custom` IdGenerator class because it would add confusion to other people working with me.

It was resolved using following change:

Adding `GenericGenerator` with `increment` strategy helped me, I made following changes to my code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="seq")
@GenericGenerator(name = "seq", strategy="increment")
@Column(name = "MY_TABLE_ID")
private Integer myTableId;

@Column(name = "MY_TABLE_NM")
private String myTableName;

//Getters Setters
}
```

It helped me because,
From [Hiberbate DOCs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/id/IncrementGenerator.html)

> **increment**
>
> An IdentifierGenerator that returns a long, constructed by counting
>   from the maximum primary key value at startup. Not safe for use in a
>   cluster!

Since, it was incrementing already existing `myTableId` even if it was *manually* inserted, this resolved my issue.

Comment: Thanks this is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

As `MY_TABLE_ID` is an identity column, following annotations will work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) // <-- IDENTITY instead of AUTO
@Column(name = "MY_TABLE_ID")
private Integer myTableId;

@Column(name = "MY_TABLE_NM")
private String myTableName;

//Getters Setters
}
```

The identity column will automatically assign an value as soon as the transaction is committed. You are not to set any values for an identity column, as its the job of the database to assign the values. Therefore you also don't need to think about any initial values (forget them completely for identity columns)

Comment: If table already has `MY_TABLE_ID`= 1, code is still trying to insert 1 for the first request and throws exception. For the second request code inserts 2 but I don't want any exception to occur.

Comment: Then is something wrong with your code. These annotations are the right ones to use

Comment: I think issue is with JPA/ORM as per these answers https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46125/why-does-postgres-generate-an-already-used-pk-value. I am not sure though. But, I am using JpaRepository.save() to insert records.

Comment: JPA is not the issue, and hibernate as well. Without more code I can't tell you more. I am using hibernate with `GenerationType.IDENTITY` in pretty much every project and I never had such an issue

Comment: With `IDENTITY` for primary key column `MY_TABLE_ID`it was trying to insert NULL and it needed database change as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544963/hibernate-generatedvalue-null-error-for-primary-key

Comment: thanks for all your help, it was resolved with `GenericGenerator` with `increment` strategy.

Answer (score 2):

You can also implement your own generator if you need more control.
See this interface [IdentifierGenerator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/id/IdentifierGenerator.html).
So you can get the count of records, for example through a [@NamedQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql).
Then you can generate an identifier yourself.

```
public class MyEntityKeyGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) {
    // SELECT count(ent) from MyEntity ent;
    Long count = (Long) session.getNamedQuery("count-query").uniqueResult();
    // calc and return id value
   }
}
```

Entity:

```
class MyEntity {
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "my_generator",
        strategy = "org.common.MyEntityKeyGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "my_generator")
private Long id;...
```

**Just do not forget about the lock.**

Comment: I don't want to create custom generator, however GenericGenerator with `increment` strategy seems to be working but I need to test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

I use the generation type Identity, which basically means that the db, takes care of Id generation.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(EntityListener.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "createdAt"})
public abstract  class AbstractEntity<ID extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private ID id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATED_AT", updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_AT")
    private Date updatedAt;

}
```

You can also use, Sequence generation:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
public class EntityWithSequenceId {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    @Id long id;
}
```

Comment: I tried both of the mentioned approaches but couldn't get it running still facing the same issue @Mehdi

Comment: Which db are you using

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: I think you should check out the solution in postgres itself, but however, I think the GenerationType Sequence will work if you use a big allocationSize, or maybe generate ID using UUID package.